How to group rows dynamically in googlesheets if they have the same data in one column
I am trying to find a script that would allow the googlesheet to group rows dynamically if column a is empty and column b is equal to the same data then it would group the row. This spreadsheet is generated from a filtered sheet so it can update dynamically when the master sheet is changed, so the row grouping would need to be updated as well if there are any changes.
The script below has done just what I needed -- it groups the filtered sheet, only excepting being it doesn't update the groups when there is a change to the filtered sheet. So if this is not possible, then can someone assist in updating this script to clear out all groups before re-running the below script again?
function groupRowsStaffInWork() {
  const groupRowsBy = 'INTEGRATIONS!B2:B';
  groupRowsByCriteria_({
    keyRange: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(groupRowsBy),
    motherRow: /^()$/i, // () means blank
    daughterRow: /^(.+)$/i, // (.+) means at least one character
    collapse: true,
  });
}

/**
* Groups all rows that meet criteria and optionally collapses the groups.
*
* @param {Object} criteria An object with this structure:
*                 {Range} keyRange The range within sheet where to find motherRows and daughterRows.
*                 {RegExp} motherRow A regular expression that identifies a value in the criteria column as a mother row.
*                 {RegExp} daughterRow A regular expression that identifies a value in the criteria column as a daughter row.
*                 {Boolean} collapse Optional. Whether to collapse the groups.
* @return {Sheet} The sheet where rows were grouped.
*/
function groupRowsByCriteria_(criteria) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 1 June 2021
  const sheet = criteria.keyRange.getSheet();
  const rowStart = criteria.keyRange.getRow();
  const rowEnd = getLastRow_(sheet);
  const keys = criteria.keyRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  const daughterRows = [];
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    if (rowStart + index <= rowEnd && key.match(criteria.daughterRow) && !key.match(criteria.motherRow)) {
      daughterRows.push(rowStart + index);
    }
  });
  const runLengths = getRunLengths_(daughterRows);
  runLengths.forEach(tuple => {
    const [start, numRows] = tuple;
    const range = sheet.getRange(start, 1, numRows);
    range.shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    if (criteria.collapse) {
      range.collapseGroups();
    }
  });
  return sheet;
}


/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}


/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}


Try a custom sort

Please explain I am trying to find a script that would allow the googlesheet to group rows dynamically if column a is empty and column b is equal to the same data then it would group the row.Please provide a few examples

Here is a sample - [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRmc64j1uq_c35ry9-X5FRh1GuCcw59ED9DnV530Yjs)  Data should flow from Master to Focused if column N contains X. And ideally would like to dynamically group rows in sheet Focused as shown. But would need to ungroup/group as needed if Master has edits and information is flowed to Focused.

Sorry but I do not follow links to other peoples accounts.
